# Cocoa way to edit id3 tag in .mp3 files?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is there a way to edit id3 tags in mp3 files in Cocoa way on OSX without using C lib such as taglib or id3lib?

I've tried using AVAssets. But I just could read the tags in mp3 files, I can't write tags to mp3 files. Does it support m4a audio file only?

I've also tried using AudioToolbox(AudioFile Get/Set Property). But I always got errors says media type is not supported.

Comment: what's wrong with these c libs?

Comment: @BryanChen Nothing wrong. But I think Cocoa way is more convenience :)

Comment: Any help with if you use qtkit?

Answer (score 0):

AVFoundation does not provide metadata keys or other functionality for MP3. You have to convert to MP4 to edit metadata within AVFoundation.